# Unable to connect remotely to custom application

Tags: linux, centos, networking, ip, tcp

I've built an application that listens on the localhost address and a specific port, lets say port 11001. Its on a remote machine with CentOS. I currently have a python script on my local machine that I'm using to communicate with the application.

I've never been able to connect to the application from my local machine. I've tried using netstat, nc, etc to no avail. I've tried to connect from other machines. I can successfully ping the remote machine from my local machine and the others I've tried to connect from but I'm unable to reach my application. I'm pretty sure the IP and port number I'm connecting to is the one that the remote application uses.

Here's the error I'm getting from the python script:

```
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I'm also able to SSH into the server but not able to connect to the remote application. I can only assume that I need to do some sort of configuring on the machine for the application.

How do I allow remote connections to the my custom application?

EDIT: The problem was iptables. I just had to configure the iptables to accept requests from the port.

Comment: If it's only listening to `localhost`, you'll never be able to connect to it from a different host. It needs to listen on the external interface.

Comment: Okay I'm a bit confused. If I have an application listening on localhost, doesn't it mean that I can connect to it using the address of the machine? I've been using scripts that listen on localhost and I'm able to connect to them using the IP address of the machine its hosted on.

Comment: Then those applications are listening on the external interface as well. If you listen only on 127.0.0.1 (`localhost`), you can only connect to whatever is listening from that machine itself.

Comment: Can you post the output of `netstat -tuln` and `iptables -L` on the machine the service is listening on?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant post the full output of the commands. I can give you the output corresponding to the application from `netstat -tuln`.

Here: `tcp        0      0 :::11001                     :::*                        LISTEN`

Comment: That should be ok for the `netstat` output, but we really need the full output of `iptables -L`. You can add the full output by simply editing the original question.

Comment: Ok, so you're not listening on `localhost`, you're listening on `0.0.0.0`, which is "all interfaces". So far, so good. I suspect the issue is with the host firewall, which is why I asked for the `iptables` output.

Comment: Hmm, so listening on 0.0.0.0 means that I can connect to it using any IP address for the machine?

Comment: Yes, assuming nothing else is blocking you.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the iptables has a record that rejects all connections. Seems like that's the issue. Let me update my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33639/discussion-between-ajpennster-and-john).

Comment: @John Note, when I do `tcpdump -i any port 11001`, I can see the requests coming in, but my application wont handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring `iptables` was the trick. I just added a rule at the top of the configuration file to accept incoming connections on port 11001 and the application started receiving requests.

I used the two following links for help:

http://fideloper.com/iptables-tutorial
http://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

First try to connect to the application on the same host where the application is running , if it works , then make the application listen on some port with ip address , let's say 192.168.1.1:5980 , then access this from your remote client (on the same LAN), and you may also need to disable firewall/iptables during testing on the server or just allow the port you want to access.Also disable the firewall on the client.